# Workflow lock "edit item"

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-api, splistitem

Is it possible to disable "edit item" in a Sharepoint List when a custom workflow is running?
Maybe a property in the workflow that can be affected?

Thanks,
David Esteves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom activity to set read-only permissions on the item in the beginning of the WF and then to restore the original permissions in the end.
Take a look at this selection of custom activities at CodePlex:
[link text](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/)